# Error You have made too many requests recently. Please, be chill. in Asana API

Tags: php, curl, asana

I have tried to send only 5 call to fetch tasks from Asana API.  Here is my code

```
$tasks = $client->fetch('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces.json');
print_r($tasks);
$i=0;

while(isset($tasks['result']['data'][$i]['id']))
{ 
    $tasks_detail = $client->fetch('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/'.$tasks['result']['data'][$i]['id'].'.json');
    print_r($tasks_detail);

    while(isset($tasks_detail['result']['data'][$i]['id']))
    { 
        $tasks_details = $client->fetch('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/'.$tasks_detail['result']['data'][$i]['id'].'.json');
        print_r($tasks_details);
        $i++;
    }
```

I have used only 2 `while` loops to fetch tasks from the API after which the api doesn't respond to the calls.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: have reformatted your code, but you aren't closing the first `while` in the code you posted.. please review it!

Comment: If `$tasks_detail['result']['data'][$i]['id']` is not set for one result from the first API call in the loop, you've produced an endless loop - resulting in unlimited API calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this situation:

```
$tasks['result']['data'][$i]['id']
```

exists and

```
$tasks_detail['result']['data'][$i]['id']
```

does not exist.

You will loop forever since the $i never gets bigger;
Consider this situation:

```
$tasks['result']['data'][1]['id']
```

exists and

```
$tasks_detail['result']['data'][1]['id']
$tasks_detail['result']['data'][2]['id']
$tasks_detail['result']['data'][3]['id']
```

exists.

next loop you will access

```
$tasks['result']['data'][4]['id']
```

directly and lose

```
$tasks['result']['data'][2]['id']
$tasks['result']['data'][3]['id']
```

.

You may want to do something like this:

```
while(isset($tasks['result']['data'][$i]['id'])){ 
    $tasks_detail = $client->fetch('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/'.$tasks['result']['data'][$i]['id'].'.json');
    print_r($tasks_detail);

    if(isset($tasks_detail['result']['data'][$i]['id'])){
        $tasks_details = $client->fetch('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/'.$tasks_detail['result']['data'][$i]['id'].'.json');
        print_r($tasks_details);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Please be careful to end the loop when you use while loop.